# Using behat to create nodes and testing user owns them

Tags: 7, testing

I would like to create a Behat test that confirms a user can only see content they own or are referenced in.  The struggle is that I can't figure out how to assign the content to created user.

Starting with something like:

```
Given users:
| name | status |
| test | 1      |
Given "Page" content:
| title | uid |
| A title | ?? |
```

I need to create several nodes to test, and it seems...odd... that I would need to do the entire steps (e.g. Then I go to register, then I go to node/add/page, ....).

How do I know the uid of the user created in the `Given`?

Comment: Are you trying to add content as a fixture/mock to test something else? What driver are you using?

Comment: @mradcliffe I'm testing that a user sees a list of content that a) they own or b) they have been referenced in.  I just found http://nuvole.org/blog/2015/mar/24/pluggable-field-handling-system-behat-drupal-extension which seems to be what I need (user "author")

Answer (score 2):

In the example in features/api.feature you'll find how to do this:

```
  Scenario: Create nodes with specific authorship
    Given users:
    | name     | mail            | status |
    | Joe User | joe@example.com | 1      |
    And "article" nodes:
    | title          | author   | body             | promote |
    | Article by Joe | Joe User | PLACEHOLDER BODY | 1       |
    When I am logged in as a user with the "administrator" role
    And I am on the homepage
    And I follow "Article by Joe"
    Then I should see the link "Joe User"
```